# more efficient loop in PLSQL

Tags: oracle, loops, plsql

i'm looking for more efficient ways to loop through PLSQL.

Requirements: imagine that i have BudgetTable & RuleSet table.
Ruleset looks something like this:

```
acc  | loc  | proj || rule1  | tag1  | prio
A1%  | L1%  | P2%  || direct | all   | 90
A12% | L12% | P23% || spread | alloc | 50
```

the first 3 columns are the where clause for the BudgetTable keys below, and store the rest of the columns..

```
A123  | L123  | P234
A199  | L199  | P299
```

and the records being picked up for each loop iteration

loop1: (A1%   | L1%   | P2%   || direct | all   | 90)

```
A123  | L123  | P234  || direct | all   | 90
A199  | L199  | P299  || direct | all   | 90
```

loop2: (A12% | L12% | P22%  || spread | alloc | 50)

```
A123  | L123  | P234  || spread | alloc | 50
```

I've done the most straightforward way, by iterating through the RuleSet table.

```
(pseudocodes)
FOR r in (select acc,loc,proj,rule1,tag1,prio from RuleSet) 
LOOP
    INSERT INTO ResultTable 
    select [columns, rule, tag1,prio ] 
    from BudgetTable 
    where acc like r.acc 
      and loc like r.loc
      and proj like r.proj
      ;
END LOOP;
```

I am looking for better ways to do this. the problem is the RuleSet can contain several thousands rules, so iterating through & matching the records one-by-one can be lengthy. I was wondering if it's possible to break the loop in several parallel stream & simultaneously run them .. 
Thanks for the input..

Comment: thanx all who replied..
so today, i was able to test both approach. (1) with the for loop (2) with cross join. 
curiously, with the budgetTable abt 10Mil rows, ruleset about 100k, my original approach with the loop is faster.
my theory is, that when dealing with large number of rows, oracle had to swap/spill over into its redo logs (or was it archive logs?) ..

Answer (score 4):

Use simple INSERT+SELECT+JOIN, it should be 30~50 timest faster than your loop:

```
INSERT INTO ResultTable 
SELECT b.columns, b.rule, b.tag1,prio  
FROM BudgetTable b
JOIN RuleSet r
ON  b.acc like r.acc 
   and b.loc like r.loc
   and b.proj like r.proj
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you don't need a loop at all:

```
INSERT INTO ResultTable 
select [columns, rule, tag1,prio ] 
from BudgetTable bt
 cross join RuleSet rs
where bt.acc like rs.acc 
  and bt.loc like rs.loc
  and bt.proj like rs.proj
  ;
```

Comment: If the ruleset is in the order of 10k rows and budget table is in the order of 20mil rows, would cross join use up too much db resources? Whereas loop would allow for frequent commit points

Comment: I guess the important number would be how many rows would typically end up being inserted.  If this is in the millions then it might be too much to do in one go.  On the other hand, if you commit periodically you could end up failing with some data inserted and some not.